# NGINX not running properly requests in my Web API

Tags: c#, nginx, web, postman, webapi

I'm new to developing web API's and I was trying to publish my small web API into my VPS. The problem is I've all setup. Later in this post ill show you the Nginx config and all of the necessary info. And the main problem I'm getting is that for example when I call my get OAuth token request it returns 200 OK but then when I put that Bearer token in each request I'm going to do the API always returns 500 status code. I have followed the Microsoft guidelines to set up the .NET Web API but I'm still having those issues. How can I solve that problem? Thanks in advance.

Get OAuth Token
[image: Get OAuth Token]

Get All Users Request with that token
[image: Get All Users Request]

Startup.cs for the API (You can find I've added the lines from the Official Microsoft Docs)

```
namespace IncidentManagerAPI
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.Configure<ForwardedHeadersOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.KnownProxies.Add(IPAddress.Parse("141.94.23.122"));
            });
            services.AddMvc();
            services.Configure<ForwardedHeadersOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.ForwardedHeaders =
                    ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto;
            });
            services.AddScoped<IUserInterface, UserService>();
            services.AddScoped<ICompanyInterface, CompanyService>();
            //services.AddControllers();
            services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "Incident Manager API", Version = "v1", Description = "Welcome to the Incident Manager API, here you will be able to test all API requests for debugging." });
                c.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
                {
                    Description = "Authorization header using the Bearer scheme. Example: \"Authorization: Bearer {token}\"",
                    Name = "Authorization",
                    In = ParameterLocation.Header,
                    Type = SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey,
                    Scheme = "bearer",
                    BearerFormat = "JWT"
                });
                c.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
                {
                        {
                            new OpenApiSecurityScheme
                            {
                                Reference = new OpenApiReference { Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme, Id = "Bearer" }
                            },
                            new List<string>()
                        }
                });
            });
            services.AddEntityFrameworkNpgsql().AddDbContext<PostgreSQLContext>(opt =>
            opt.UseNpgsql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("PostgreSQLConnection")));
            services
                .AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddScheme<AuthenticationSchemeOptions, BasicAuthenticationHandler>("BasicAuthentication", options => { })
                .AddJwtBearer(options =>
                {
                    options.SaveToken = true;
                    options.TokenValidationParameters = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters()
                    {
                        ValidIssuer = "incidentmanagerapi",
                        ValidAudience = "testuser",
                        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("testpassword")),
                        ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
                    };
                });
            services.AddAuthorization(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).RequireAuthenticatedUser().Build();
                options.AddPolicy("BasicAuthentication", new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder("BasicAuthentication").RequireAuthenticatedUser().Build());
            });
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions
            {
                ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto
            });

            app.UseAuthentication();

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseSwagger();
            app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "MyAPI");
                c.RoutePrefix = string.Empty;
            });

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Nginx configuration:

```
    server {

    # SSL configuration
    #
    # listen 443 ssl default_server;
    # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
    #
    # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
    #
    # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
    #
    # Self-signed certs generated by the SSL-cert package
    # Don't use them in a production server!
    #
    # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

    root /var/www/html/incidentmanagerapi;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name api.incidentmanagerapp.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:5000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   Connection keep-alive;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

    # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #   include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    #
    #   # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
    #   fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
    #   # With php-cgi (or other tcp sockets):
    #   fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    #}

    # deny access to .htaccess files if Apache's document root
    # concurs with Nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #   deny all;
    #}

    listen [::]:443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.incidentmanagerapp.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.incidentmanagerapp.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}


# Virtual Host configuration for example.com
#
# You can move that to a different file under sites-available/ and symlink that
# to sites-enabled/ to enable it.
#
#server {
#   listen 80;
#   listen [::]:80;
#
#   server_name example.com;
#
#   root /var/www/example.com;
#   index index.html;
#
#   location / {
#       try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
#   }
#}

server {
    if ($host = api.incidentmanagerapp.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name api.incidentmanagerapp.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

**Edited:**

I have enabled the logs in C# but still don't know how to solve the problem:

```
    System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at IncidentManagerAPI.Controllers.UserService.GetUsers() in C:\Users\alexm\Documents\Projects\.NET\incident-manager-api\IncidentManagerAPI\Services\UserService.cs:line 33
   at IncidentManagerAPI.Controllers.UserController.GetUsers() in C:\Users\alexm\Documents\Projects\.NET\incident-manager-api\IncidentManagerAPI\Controllers\UserController.cs:line 26
   at lambda_method9(Closure , Object )
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.AwaitableObjectResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, ValueTask`1 actionResultValueTask)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeInnerFilterAsync>g__Awaited|13_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|24_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|19_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.Policy.AuthorizationMiddlewareResultHandler.HandleAsync(RequestDelegate next, HttpContext context, AuthorizationPolicy policy, PolicyAuthorizationResult authorizeResult)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

HEADERS
=======
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip
Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1bmlxdWVfbmFtZSI6ImluY2lkZW50bWFuYWdlcmFwcCIsIm5iZiI6MTYyMDIwMjczMCwiZXhwIjoxNjIwMjg5MTMwLCJpYXQiOjE2MjAyMDI3MzAsImlzcyI6ImluY2lkZW50bWFuYWdlcmFwaSIsImF1ZCI6ImluY2lkZW50bWFuYWdlcmFwcCJ9.8-bOVZwpL65sfjSgiebhTipqXZ0Hsy3KIT0cdC22rEs
Cookie: __cfduid=d84134facb9aef7a8993712bbf57b8a5c1617971031
Host: api.incidentmanagerapp.com
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.28.0
X-Forwarded-For: 81.184.7.139
CF-IPCountry: ES
CF-RAY: 64a89a9f2e08b7c9-CDG
CF-Visitor: {"scheme":"https"}
Postman-Token: 06151a4e-e608-43d5-ba42-999f1bfd37b4
CF-Connecting-IP: 81.184.7.139
CDN-Loop: cloudflare
cf-request-id: 09dd3ef77a0000b7c926288000000001
X-Original-For: 127.0.0.1:44558
X-Original-Proto: http
```

UPDATED:

The problem was I didn't have permission in the Database Schema.

Answer (score 0):

The NGINX configuration seems alright and I'm not that much of a C# guy so not sure about that part.

If you don't see something worth fixing in your application error logs than it's probably NGINX. Can you post the last few lines from your NGINX error log?

Comment: Just found this in the access.log of nginx: https://controlc.com/230c8ab9

Comment: Anything on the `/etc/nginx/error.log` file?

Comment: Nothing strange, but thanks for telling me that.